Are the teachings on divorce and remarriage in the Bible 100% conclusive?
In 1 Corinthians 7:10-11 it says:

To the married I give this command (not I, but the Lord): A wife must not separate from her husband.  But if she does, she must remain unmarried or else be reconciled to her husband.  And a husband must not divorce his wife.

Then it goes on to say in 1 Corinthians 7:12-15:

To the rest I say this (I, not the Lord): If any brother has a wife who is not a believer and she is willing to live with him, he must not divorce her.  And if a woman has a husband who is not a believer and he is willing to live with her, she must not divorce him.  For the unbelieving husband has been sanctified through his wife, and the unbelieving wife has been sanctified through her believing husband. Otherwise your children would be unclean, but as it is, they are holy.  But if the unbeliever leaves, let it be so.  The brother or the sister is not bound in such circumstances; God has called us to live in peace.

Then later, in 1 Corinthians 7:39 it says:

A woman is bound to her husband as long as he lives. But if her husband dies, she is free to marry anyone she wishes, but he must belong to the Lord."

Is the Apostle Paul saying that divorce and remarriage are generally disallowed, but in certain extreme/unique situations, like an unbeliever refusing to stay married to you, God would allow it?  Does this open the possibility to other exceptions, such as physical abuse?  What is the correct interpretation?

Five years ago in an annual ETS meeting, Wayne Grudem presented a fascinating paper which evaluated the "in such circumstances" phrase in 1 Corinthians 7:15. In the paper he evaluated the use and meaning of this phrase in non-biblical Greek writings and made a good case that this phrase indicates that the specific condition standing before the phrase is but an example taken from a variety of conditions which are being addressed. Hence, abandonment due to the Christian/non-Christian condition is but one form of abandonment for which divorce is permitted. Grudem's specific concern was over abuse situations, which are in effect a form of abandonment, where one no longer abides by their marital obligations and duties to the other. I would add the sexual immorality situation, which Jesus addressed in Matthew 19:9, the obligations under 1 Corinthians 7:3, and the death of the spouse (7:39). Abandonment takes many forms.
Of course, we must be cautious here, as there may be situations in which the one claiming perceived abuse may themselves be the one abandoning the marriage, for insufficient cause. So let us not too lightly take recourse to this allowance. God hates divorce. Further, marriage is to be illustrative of the loving relationship between Christ and the church (Eph. 5:22-33). And yet, situations of abuse and abandonment are real, and I believe that this passage offers release. In such situations remarriage is also sanctioned.

I received a negative vote, with no comment? Huh?

I received two negative votes and a comment that doesn't have any obvious point.

Well, I can at least affirm your response (+1).

I would summarize it as:
If you are married to an unbeliever:

if they divorce you, you are free to remarry.
if they are willing to stay with you, that's good, stay with them.
if you divorce them, you are not free to remarry as long as they live.
if you do remarry, it must be to a believer.

This is all about believer versus unbeliever, independent of any other reason why one might want to end a marriage.

Art thou loosed from a wife ? Seek not a wife. *But and if thou hast married, thou hast not sinned indicates re-marriage (of a man) after loosing.
